# "Method Name Expected" when setting up event handler

Tags: c#, event-handling

I am trying to create a timer for a Project class (multiple instances) which when elapsed will call a static method from another class (BuildEngine.AddBuild) to add itself (the project) to a build queue.

I get the following error:

```
Error   4   Method name expected
```

Build Engine Class:

```
        // Set timers for builds
        _Logger.Log("Scheduling Builds ...");
        foreach (Project project in _ProjectList)
        {
            switch (project.TriggerType)
            {
                case "Scheduled":
                    TimeSpan nowTime = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, 0);
                    TimeSpan projectTime = project.Time;
                    project.ProjectTimer = new Timer(nowTime.Subtract(projectTime).TotalMilliseconds);
                    project.ProjectTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(BuildEngine.AddBuild(project));
                    project.ProjectTimer.AutoReset = true;
                    project.ProjectTimer.Enabled = true;
                    break;
                case "Continuous":

                    break;
            }
        }
```

BuildEngine.AddBuild():

```
    public static void AddBuild(Project project)
    {
        Build build = new Build();
        build.Project = project;
        build.BuildNumber = -1;
        build.BuildStatus = BuildStatus.NotBuilding;

        _BuildQueue.Add(build);
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you have code outside a method.  You can't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the `BuildEngine` method does not match that of the [`ElapsedEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.elapsedeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate, and even if it did, you can't provide parameters to it like that.

Try binding the event to [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) (also called an anonymous function) instead:

```
project.ProjectTimer.Elapsed += (s, e) => BuildEngine.AddBuild(project);
```